# What does it mean when we say a variable changes linearly?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, simulation

I know that probably my question is a bit silly/simple but I will be thankful if anyone could help me.
I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcXhs.jpg) in which a variable is defined for an object somehow that it linearly decreases from 500 micrometers at the top of the object to 50 micrometers at the bottom of the object. I was wondering what does it mean by linearly decreases?
I know that it means that the variable decreases slowly from top to bottom of the object but can anyone explain the linear decrease in more detail?

Any response or feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could it mean as opposed to logarithmically? Like the scale from 500 to 50 is linearly divided as on a ruler e.g. half way in between is 275.

Comment: @imu96 thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I do not know. Could you please explain further?

Comment: You have to identify your independent variable, not just your dependent variable. Your tags of (numerical) linear algebra and change of variable are not appropriate here. This is basic precalculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for your comment about the tags, I did not know it. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two variables $v_1$ and $v_2$ having a 'linear' relationship in this context probably means that the function relating them is affine (has a straight-line graph $v_2=m\,v_1+c$ for some nonzero $m$); in other words, there is some constant $c$ such that $v_2-c$ is directly proportional to $v_1.$